# How to reference components in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am referencing some  components in my Vb.net project. I am trying put it in such a way that the program always looks for the .dll files in the current application location.

If the application is in `C:\Program` Files then the reference path for the .dll files should be `C:Program\name.dll`

Is this possible? I am trying to to make the application portable so that I need not install the required .dll files in every other computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a file reference ([Add References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) dialog - select `Browse`), the file paths are relative.

Regardless of that, the assembly loader will look at the application directory for the referenced DLLs (or the `bin` folder for web applications).

You need to ensure that you are not referencing assemblies in the GAC (or, if you are, you need to distribute them with your application).

Comment: you mean I have to put in the bin folder and it will be automatically detected ?

Comment: @Failed_Noob - if it is a .NET assembly, yes.

Comment: @Oded - In the bin Folder there are two other folders, Debug and Release.  Should I put them there ?

Comment: @Failed_Noob - Just add a reference the way I described. The dll's will get automatically copied to the right bin folders. When you deploy, they will also be copied.

Comment: @Oded - I have already done this "add a reference in Visual Basic" (as given in msdn). but  there is nothing in my bin folder. can u put up in procedure in step by step manner?

Comment: @Failed_Noob - did you build the project?

Comment: @Failed_Noob - No, I mean, in Visual Studio, click the build button (F5).

Comment: @Oded - Nothing in bin folder or any other folder inside it :( . You want me to put up a screen shot of my references ?

Comment: @Failed_Noob - How have you added them? Did you browse to the dlls?

Comment: @Oded Yes I Went To project properties, in references section, I clicked on Add button, add dialog box pops up. In the Browse tab I browsed for my dll and finally clicked on OK.